# Custom Auth using OWIN on Asp Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am trying to create a login screen using owin on Asp MVC.
This is the code that is in the controller.

I have even tried hard coding the values but I still get a 401 when I try enter the dashboard after login.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        int userId = 0;
        string role = string.Empty;

        if (new UserManager().IsValid(username, password, ref userId, ref role))
        {
            var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
              new[] { 
          // adding following 2 claim just for supporting default antiforgery provider
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId.ToString()),
          new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),

          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,username),

          // optionally you could add roles if any
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)

              },
              DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
               new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);
            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard"); // auth succeed 
        }
        // invalid username or password
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid username or password");
        return View("Index", "_LayoutUnAuthorised");
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Default")]
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {



        return View();
    }
```

My startup file is empty am I missing something here

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you missed the Owin Cookie Configuration on Startup class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOn"),
    });
}
```

Install Nuget Package `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` then you are good to go